# How to control number of cores and processors in Python when we need to share state between processes

Tags: python, linux, python-multiprocessing

In [document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), an example is shown about how to share state between processes. For the sake of time, I post the code in the document below.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

I am writing codes on a Linux supercomputing system, where I am allowed to assign a fixed number of cores and a number of cores per node. So how can I write a code to assign workers in this frame? Will Python make full use of cores automatically? And what is a correct way to assign parameters in order to make good use of competing resource in this frame?

Comment: You ask about shared state or about starting multiple processes? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @lesingerouge I do know how to start mp and share state, but what I don't know is how to assign workers, cores or process under this frame. For example, we can use `p=Pool(5)` to assign 5 workers. So if I plan to use `Pool()`, where do I need to insert it under this frame? If `Pool()` is not correct answer here, what should be correct to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible answer:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Pool
import random

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    a[random.randint(5)] = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    # you can manually set the number of workers
    workers = 5
    # or, if you want to use all cores, 
    # use the maximum number of existing cores to set workers
    # workers = cpu_count()
    p = Pool(workers)
    results = p.map(f, (num, arr))

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

In the code above, the print statements at the end should print `3.1415927` and `[0,0,0,0,0,6,7,8,9]`.

If you want to use Process, you have to manually setup and manage the start and end of each process:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array, Pool
import random

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    a[random.randint(5)] = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    # if you want to use all cores, 
    # use the maximum number of existing cores to set workers
    workers = cpu_count()
    prcs = [Process(target=f, args=(num, arr)).start() for i in range(workers)]
    results = [i.join() for i in prcs]

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

Comment: I haven't test it yet, but thanks. So #workers = #cores = #process right?

Comment: And if I don't use `Pool`,will it automatically use all cores available?

Comment: Edited to answer your comments.